# Additional CSS for sub-categories using Layout Updates

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

I'm working on a site that has a design for parent categories and a different design for sub-categories. The only difference, at the moment, is the CSS. The sub-category has CSS that overrides the parent category's CSS.

I realize I could use the Layout Update XML, but would prefer to make it easier for the end user by just selecting a Layout from the drop-down. I tried creating my own layout, but the page layouts are only containers and catalog_category_view.xml applies to all categories.

Is there a way to create a new Layout that also updates the CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to have two themes, one for each category and the subcategory create the desired design there, and you can change the admin backend theme to load on that category or subcategory

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did, but it seemed overkill for something that seems like it would be simple on any other platform. Also there was some CSS that was getting hard to mange between the two.

Comment: You create fallback of parent theme ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to work well with setting extends, for instance web/css/soruce/_navigation_extend.less. It works on the parent theme but not the child theme, and I don't have anything else overwriting it.